# jQuery not sending headers for basic auth

Tags: jquery, ajax, limejs

I've tried every example I've seen on stackoverflow and I still cannot get jquery to include the authorization. I am user **jQuery 1.11.3**. Here is my ajax call

```
var headers = "Basic "+username+":"+password;
var data = $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://55.55.55.55:6025/users",
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        beforeSend : function(xhr) {
          xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", headers);
        },
        xhrFields: {
          withCredentials: 'true'
        },
        processData: 'false'
})
data.done(function (result) {
    console.log(result);
})
data.fail(function (result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

I have also tried this:

```
var data = $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://104.236.169.12:6025/users",
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    username: creds[0],
    password: creds[1]
})
```

Why is this not including an authorization field in the request headers?

I am also using limejs. So if there is some kind of CORS functionality inside that that I am not getting, would someone please point that out?

**EDIT**

I found this method that seems to be working:

```
var data = $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://user@email.edu:pass@104.236.169.12:6025/users",
    dataType: 'jsonp'
})
```

but it sends the credentials in plain text in the http request. Is this a safe method?

Comment: you can't send headers with JSONP.

Comment: See my update. I tried it with just the username and password too

Comment: That doesn't change my first comment.

Comment: Please don't comment on here unless you are going to contribute something that will help me find an answer

Comment: YOU CANNOT USE `datatype:'jsonp'` IF YOU EXPECT TO SEND HEADERS TO THE SERVER. is that any more clear? I'm trying to help you solve this problem.

Comment: JSONP requests are done by appending a <script> tag to you document. You cannot send headers with a script tag, therefore it is impossible to send headers with a jsonp request. If you MUST use JSONP, then your last snippet is the only option. and, no, it isn't safe.

Comment: Okay, I'm sorry. I stopped using jsonp on the API and I found something that is working. Thank you